# ConfirmEmailAsync always return Invalid Token when using CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a requirement to override the default expiration time for EmailConfirmation. I have the following code:

```
public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
                                                    IOptions<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options,
                                                    ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger)
        : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    
}
```

and the following in Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;

    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = nameof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>);
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<FusionFlowDbContext>()
.AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddTokenProvider<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>(nameof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>))
.AddSignInManager();

// Set expiration time for confirmation links 
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
    options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(confirmationLinksExpirationInMinutes));
services.Configure<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
    options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(emailConfirmationLinksExpirationInMinutes));
```

However whenever I call `userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync` I get `Invalid Token`.
Token is the same as the one that is generated when calling `userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`.
If I remove the CustomTokenProvider `userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` works without any issues.

Anyone can assist?

Comment: How many minutes you're setting for the link to expire?

Comment: I know I've read about this problem before, and too bad for us, my memory fails me here. So, if this is wrong, forgive me. It may be that you'd need to not just inherit the `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>` but also implement the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser>` interface.

Comment: See if this article helps you: https://newbedev.com/asp-net-identity-2-giving-invalid-token-error
In my case it was token encoding error.